# How to identify app source of SCHANNEL error?

Tags: iis-7, tls1.2, windows-server-2008-r2, schannel

Recently used [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to disable protocols less than TLS 1.2 on the IIS web server.  Starting to see numerous SCHANNEL errors in the event log like so:

> A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

How do you determine which app is logging this error?

Comment: Take a look at:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0c6be79-9a07-4705-aa55-833e01420a59/tls-11-and-12-event-a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-an-ssl-client-credential-the-internal?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: This looks promising too : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/enable-schannel-event-logging

Answer (score 1):

The event log gives you the process ID. Open the event in question and go to the Details tab. Expand the `System` element, then the `Execution` element. Under that you should see a `ProcessID` attribute. Make a note of the value.

Open Task Manager and go to the Details tab. Find your process ID (PID) in the list and look at the Name column to get the corresponding process name.